# why can't you initialize values of structs outside of main() in c?

Tags: c, struct, structure

I get an error in visual studio with the code:

```
struct coordinates {
    int x;
    int y;
};
struct coordinates point;
point.x = 5;
point.y = 3;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

it works if I initialize `point.x` and `point.y` in `main()` and / or if I give the point values like this: `struct coordinates point = {5, 3}`. Why can't you initialize `point.x` and `point.y` outside of `main()`?

Comment: Why would you wish to do this?

Comment: @EdHeal If you think about it from the perspective of  JavaScript programmer - it makes sense and is more legible and readable than the more cryptic initialization syntax used in C.

Comment: @EdHeal I don't wish to do that. I'm just curious why i is the way it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The form you've written is *not initialization*; it's an uninitialized (or rather default-initialized, to zero) declaration and definition followed by assignment statements outside of a scope where they're valid.

If you want to initialize the members by name, write:

```
struct coordinates point = {
    .x = 5,
    .y = 3,
};
```

Comment: I'm beginning to see a pattern: if I define the variable `a` outside of `main` and afterwards change its value (still outside of `main`), I will get an error. So since `point.x` and `point.y` are set to 0 by default, I can't change them, correct?

Comment: @Natrium - you can set them, once, in a named way as this answer indicates. You're not ever "changing" them though-- this syntax isn't "executed" at all in the way that you might expect-- it's used an instruction to the compiler that *this variable* should have *this value* at startup. That information is preserved in the output program as a special condition, differently to being encoded as an executable statement. I have written another answer here with a bit more background on that notion.

Answer (score 6):

Other answers are (correctly) explaining that there *are* ways to initialize structs by named member outside `main` statically but I want to add, for the OP or for others.

The basic idea here is that C doesn't allow executable statements ("code") outside of functions. A new C programmer may be coming from another language where code is sort of frequently executed in a "global scope" and you define functions or set variables here and there as you wish. C is way older and much more structured than this. There are global variables (like your `point`), which are things you declare outside of any particular function, but you can't really "do stuff" with those variables in the global space itself, except indicate their initial values (static initialization).

C doesn't "run through the file executing everything it finds in order"-- each file gets compiled into a unit of object code which then gets linked together with other units and `main` is (essentially) the entry point for execution, which in turn calls other functions, and so on-- when your code is running, its always "inside" of a function somewhere.

It is true that ordering of declarations and definitions within a file matter in C, but this is essentially for the convenience of the compiler, not because things are "executed" or "evaluated" in that order at runtime. (By the time your code is executing, it's been utterly transformed into something else and the order of statements in the original files has essentially disappeared from view.)

So! With all that said: it is useful and often desirable to have the values of global variables pre-set at program initialization time. So static initialization is sort of special in that it sorta *looks like* an executable statement but isn't, and thus it has traditionally had a goofy syntax. We had that sort of strange ordered `= {2, 3}` syntax, and now there are more accommodations for the named members to help you accomplish this static initialization. But you should still think of it as static (one-time, fixed) initialization, not as executing an assignment in the global space, because that isn't what you're actually doing.

Answer (score 2):

> Why can't you initialize point.x and point.y outside of main()?

You can, [using static initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521927/initializing-a-global-struct-in-c) - but you can't call a function or perform impure operations. When using static-initialization prior to C99 you need to ensure fields are set in the correct order, while C99 and later allow for [designated initializers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/designated-initializers-c/) that allow arbitrary field initialization.

C code outside of a function are not executable instructions - they're static declarations, consequently they don't have a defined evaluation order.

As a thought-experiment, consider this:

```
int x;
int y;

x = 2;
y = 3;
y = x;
x = y;

int main() {
    
    return x; // what is returned?
}
```

Comment: C90 does not have designated initializers. It has legacy structure initialization that depends on knowing the order of the members.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Whoops! Thanks - I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you learned Javascript but you are a newbie in c/c++.
Every c/c++ program starts with the `main` function, and every executive code must be in a function.

So if you want to initialize the value of a struct, you should do this in main function.

```
struct coordinates {
    int x;
    int y;
};
struct coordinate point;
int main(){
  point.x = 5;
  point.y = 3;
}
```

Comment: C does allow for static-initialization, so you **don't** need to initialize static structs inside `main`. Don't forget that `main` is not necessarily the first code that runs in a program either.

Comment: futhermore ... what you do in `main()` is not initialization but assignment.